# What is the best way to include a GitHub page in my resume?

Tags: resume, internship, software-development

I'm a rising sophomore looking for opportunities for my Major and career. I've been told over and over to include my GitHub page in my resume as it's a way for potential employers to gauge my skill and past projects. However, most of my projects are private and can't be made public. How can I still showcase my works on GitHub/showcase my GitHub profile on my resume?

Answer (score 4):

> I've been told over and over to include my Github page in my resume as
> it's a way for potential employers to gauge my skill and past projects

That's usually a very good idea to get through the CV screening. You will usually want to include this as a few lines somewhere in your experience, together with a link they can follow to see the code you've written (or other contributions you've done, contributing to documentation/project management are as if not more valuable).

> However, most of my projects are private and can't be made public. How
> can I still showcase my works on Github/showcase my Github profile on
> my resume?

So far you have nothing that you can showcase, as all your work cannot be shared with the public. The only way to go around that is to actually do some open source work, it can be in the form of contribution to existing projects, or something you built on your own.

Whether that's worth the effort you have to figure out for yourself. A general guideline would be that if you have a thin CV experience wise, or simply struggling to get past the CV reading stage then this will help with both items. But if you have decades of experience then some minor open source contributions won't matter much. Although that greatly varies from company to company, I know some who outright require for every candidate to have opensource contributions as that's part of their philosophy, and then even a few hours worth of them can make the difference between bin and an invitation.

Answer (score 2):

While there is little you can do to make your projects public by default (due to NDAs, school anti-plagiarism rules, etc.), there are a few possible alternative solutions:

1. Place a link to your GitHub profile besides your contact information. You would have your phone number, address/location, and then your GitHub profile.

   - This would only be beneficial if you had projects that you could show and could make public.
2. If you made a video for a certain project (e.g. a product demo video), upload the video to YouTube. Place the link to the YouTube video besides the project on your resume.
3. If you are allowed show your code to other people (even if the repositories are private), you could potentially show it during interviews if the opportunity arose.

Example for item 2 (where the link would be the specific video):

> “Project Title” Project 
> Sept – Dec 2019
> *Course Code*: *Course Title* | [YouTube](https://youtube.com/)

Answer (score 1):

I stuff it in the top along with my other contact information, such as my LinkedIn and DevPost. I make them both nice clickable hyperlinks as well as easy to just type into the web browser.

Like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In the top section of my Resume I am adding link to my Github Profile preceeded with Github logo.

[image: Github Image]

When it comes to marking invidual links to repositories in the Resume I am adding small clickable icon at the end of name of each project in order to get to the repository.

[image]

I think it's very good way to do it as it is not super intrusive and takes very little space to add links to your repositories. Less technical people will ignore it and it will not take priceless vertical space.